# cannot complete Purchases in Sandbox Mode for in app purchase in iPhone

Tags: ios

I am developing an In App Purchase Application,
My application already is in AppStore.  I created new application, in which i am integrating in-App Purchase. I Created Sandbox account (Selected Country US). I launched the application and moved to the iTunes, Clicked on the install. It is displaying the popup with Use Existing Apple Id, Create Apple ID ,cancel. I am entering the Apple Id and Password (sandbox). and then it is Displaying an pop up with Following message.
"Cannot Complete Purchase in Sandbox Mode

The purchase of "App Name" for $0.00 was successful,but Transactions can not be completed in sandbox mode.

[Environment : Sandbox]"

Comment: Got this issue as well. Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use normal Apple ID in sandbox. You have to create test users in your iTunes Connect. Information about creating test accounts can be found in [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/7_ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH2-SW1).

Comment: The one which i used is sandbox test user Account only. I created it using iTunes Connect only.

Comment: Now you can use a normal user with the sandbox.